# How to Implement OR function on my queryset

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

I have currently created a model as shown below

```
class Customer(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True,default='')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
```

In my views.py

I have,

```
    customer_list =  Customer.objects.all()

    myFilter1 = CustomerlistFilter(request.GET,queryset=customer_list)
    customer_list = myFilter1.qs
```

And within my filters.py I have written what is shown below

```
class CustomerlistFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    id = CharFilter(lookup_expr='icontains')
    first_name = CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    middle_name = CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')
    last_name = CharFilter(lookup_expr='iexact')


    class Meta:
        model = Customer
        fields = ['id', 'first_name', 'middle_name', 'last_name']
```

Is there way of implementing the OR function, so that I can have one search box instead of multiple boxes for each field?

Answer (score 0):

I think then you do not have to use a `FilterSet`, since a `FilterSet` is, well, a *set* of ways to filtering.

You can just filter withh:

```
from django.db.models import Q

customer_list =  Customer.objects.filter(
    Q(id__icontains=search_query) |
    Q(first_name__icontains=search_query) |
    Q(middle_name__icontains=search_query) |
    Q(last_name__icontains=search_query)
)
```

If the searchbox has as `name="…"`, then you can obtain the value in the search box with:

```
search_query = request.GET.get('name-of-input-item')
```

Comment: Would  "search_query = request.GET.get('name-of-input-item')" substitute  "myFilter1 = CustomerlistFilter(request.GET,queryset=customer_list)"

Comment: @kamcoder: no, this obtain the data you submitted in the form (note that `name-of-input-item` should be replaced with the value in the `name="..." atribute of the `<input>` element)... You *then* filter the `Customer.objects.all()` queryset with the `Customer.objects.filter(..)`.

Comment: I understand, is filters.py needed in this case?

Comment: Thanks sir, I appreciate the help.